# Android Studio emulator with very small screen without the app name and icons

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

How do I get the app name and icons out of the android studio emulator? I have a really small screen and the emulator should show nothing but the screen. Now it doesn't show the actual screen at all.

[emulator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erKk0.jpg)

Comment: That seems like an unrealistic emulator configuration. What device are you trying to emulate?

Comment: RealWear HMT-1 device. 0.33 inch diagonal and WVGA (854×480)

Comment: OK, that's wild. In theory, you would want to switch to a theme that does not have the app bar (the blue bar with "HMT-1" in it in your screenshot) and [enable immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive). However, you might want to look at RealWear's sample apps to see how they approach this. For highly customized environments like this, the manufacturer often is a better source of information.

Comment: Maybe I need to do without an emulator. I was surprised myself that it became so difficult and these icons always show up by default, even though I haven’t even chosen any skin. I'm a complete beginner with Android dev.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. They have some stuff in Github.